# Generic call to a non static method of a abstract class c#

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

In my code I have enums like `Vehicle`, `ParkingArea` etc. and I have extended them so that the user can make use of the default Vehicle and `ParkingArea` values and also add/update their own which gets saved in the database. 
I have a abstract class like so ,

```
public abstract class EnumExtension<T> where T : struct
{
   public bool updateEnum(string name){
     //code to update the enum extension
   }
}
```

And there is a controller like the following to access the above update method

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{   
   public void UpdateAnyEnum(string newName, int value, string typeName){
     var enum_1 = (EnumExtensionForVehicle)value;
     enum_1.updateEnum(newName);
   }
}
```

I need to make this method `UpdateAnyEnum`  generic since I do not know whether the user is trying to update the `Vehicle` or `ParkingArea`
In this method I need to determine `EnumExtensionForVehicle` dynamically and make a call to `updateEnum`
The `typeName` parameter consists the type of enum I am trying to edit i.e either `Vehicle` or `ParkingArea`

I need to make `UpdateAnyEnum` a generic method. Any thoughts and ideas are much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How would you expect the cast from `int` to `EnumExtensionForVehicle` work at the moment? Do you have a custom conversion in each concrete class? It would help if you'd give a short but complete example here - otherwise we'll be guessing things and might get it wrong.

Comment: I don´t understand your question. How should you API know if `3` for example means `Vehicle` and not `ParkingArea`? Is this why you want `UpdateAnyEnum` to be generic? To provide that information: `UpdateAnyEnum<Vehicle(theName, 3, theTpe)`?

Comment: This question really doesn't make any sense to me. What exactly are you updating here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you determine the class to call. In general you need a reference of EnumExtension in UpdateAnyEnum. And for value of T you need to make it UpdateAnyEnum generic. Something like below.

Note: Below code is not tested. Its just an idea of how code should work

```
public abstract class EnumExtension<T> where T : struct
{
   public bool updateEnum(string name){
     //code to update the enum extension
   }
}

public class EnumExtensionForVehicle : EnumExtension<Vehicle>
{
   public bool updateEnum(string name){
     //code to update the enum extension
   }
}

public class EnumExtensionForParkingArea : EnumExtension<ParkingArea>
{
   public bool updateEnum(string name){
     //code to update the enum extension
   }
}

public class MyController : ApiController
{   
   public void UpdateAnyEnum<T>(string newName, int value, string typeName) {
        EnumExtension<T> factory;

        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "Vehicle":
                factory = new EnumExtensionForVehicle();
                break;
            case "ParkingArea":
                factory = new EnumExtensionForParkingArea();
                break;
        }

        factory.updateEnum(newName);
   }
}
```